# RxSwift) issue with subscribing to a completable event using flatMap

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rx-swift

```swift
func someCompletable() -> Completable {
    return Completable.create { observer in
        observer(.completed)
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

```swift
let buttonDidTap = PublishRelay<Void>()

buttonDidTap
    .debug()
    .subscribe()
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I see that the next() event is fired when the buttonDidTap is tapped.

However, when I convert it to the Completable type via flatMap, no events are emitted after flatMap.

```swift
buttonDidTap
    .flatMap { self.someCompletable() } 
    .debug()
    .subscribe()
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I have also tried subscribing to all the events onNext, onCompletable, onError, and onDisposed, but none of them are emitted.
Any idea why this is?

Here's a gif run screen for this
: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/57667738/229386647-c061d185-2015-40af-9150-5daac58c47ec.gif

```swift
buttonDidTap
    .debug() //onNext event fired
    .flatMap { self.someCompletable() } 
    .debug() //no event fired
    .subscribe()
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

My guess is that the flatMap loses the Completable traits in the process of converting a Completable to an Observable and reverts to the form of an Observable.
Therefore, the call to onCompleted seems to disappear.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `flatMap` cannot complete until every observable that it is following completes. Otherwise it wouldn't be able to respond to any more events. For example, the next time the button is tapped.

So when the completable emits a completed event, what is the flatMap supposed to do?

- It can't emit a next event because the completable didn't emit a next event.
- It can't emit an error event because there was no error. If the completable *did* emit an error, then it could.
- It can't emit a completed event because it is still monitoring the button tap for more next events.

For this reason, you see no events come out of the flatMap (until either an error is emitted further up the chain or all of the completable subscriptions *and* the button tap observable have completed.)

If you want to know when the completable has actually completed, you need to convert that completed event into a next event. For example:

```
buttonDidTap
    .flatMap { someCompletable.andThen(Observable.just(())) }
```

This way, the observable returned from flatMap will emit a `.next(())` event every time `someCompletable` completes.

### Additionally

The code you posted:

```
buttonDidTap
    .debug() //onNext event fired
    .flatMap { self.someCompletable() } 
    .debug() //no event fired
    .subscribe()
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

likely has a retain cycle. Since the closure passed to `flatMap` retains `self` and the disposeBag is retained by `self`. This means that `self` tangentially retains itself.

To remove the cycle, create the Completable outside of the closure:

```
let completable = someCompletable()
buttonDidTap
    .debug() //onNext event fired
    .flatMap { completable } 
    .debug() //no event fired
    .subscribe()
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

This works because every time the Completable is subscribed to, it will call the closure you passed to its constructor.

Comment: So, In order to handle the onComplete block in a subscribe to a flatMap, both the sub-observables and the source observable(buttonDidTap in this case) must be complete. I get it, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @SHKIM It sounds like the answer was helpful and should be accepted as correct. Yes?

Comment: I'm new to Stackoverflow and didn't realize the accept button existed. I just hit it. Thanks a lot!